# Why does concatenation in Python appear to be getting slower?

Tags: python, concatenation, profiling

Why does it appear that concatenation in Python 3 is slower in some cases than in Python 2?

The most impacted method of concatenation appears to be successive concatenation of `bytes` objects, which has gone from an O(n) to O(n²) operation.

The bulk of my profiling code is here:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from operator import concat
from sys import version, version_info
from timeit import timeit  # Compatibility: ver >= 2.6

# ver = version.partition('\n')[0].rstrip()
ver = '.'.join(str(v) for v in version_info[:3])
print(ver)

if version_info[0] == 2:
    from StringIO import StringIO
else:
    from io import StringIO
    from functools import reduce
    xrange = range


def build_plus():
    output = ''
    for _ in xrange(input_len):
        output += 'a'
    return output


def build_join():
    return ''.join('a' for _ in xrange(input_len))


def build_bytes_plus():
    output = b''
    for _ in xrange(input_len):
        output += b'a'
    return output


def build_stringio():
    output = StringIO()
    for _ in xrange(input_len):
        output.write('a')
    return output.getvalue()


def build_reduce():
    return reduce(concat, ('a' for _ in xrange(input_len)))


builds = {'str+': build_plus,
          'join': build_join,
          'reduce': build_reduce,
          'bytes+': build_bytes_plus,
          'StringIO': build_stringio}

if version_info[0] == 2:
    import cStringIO

    def build_cstringio():
        output = cStringIO.StringIO()
        for _ in xrange(input_len):
            output.write('a')
        return output.getvalue()

    builds['cStringIO'] = build_cstringio
else:
    from io import BytesIO

    def build_bytesio():
        output = BytesIO()
        for _ in xrange(input_len):
            output.write(b'a')
        return output.getvalue()

    builds['BytesIO'] = build_bytesio

resfile = open('times.csv', 'a')
size_range = 50  # Number of points over the size axis
min_order = 1.0  # 10^x byte input min
max_order = 5.0  # 10^x byte input max

for allow_gc in (False, True):
    setup = 'gc.enable()' if allow_gc else 'pass'

    for build_name, build_fun in builds.items():
        # For a roughly constant confidence interval, aim for uniform sample density across the
        # (logarithmic) input size axis.
        for size_index in range(size_range+1):
            input_len = int(10**((max_order-min_order)*size_index/size_range + min_order))

            # Rather than repeating many measurements at one input size, perform one measurement
            # per input size for a continuous range of input sizes and apply smoothing later.
            dur = timeit(build_fun, setup, number=1)

            resfile.write('"%s",%s,"%s",%d,%.6g\n' % (ver, str(allow_gc).upper(), build_name,
                                                      input_len, dur))
```

Some graphs from my R script shown here:

[image: String append across Python versions]

[image: String append time complexity]

Comment: yes, `+` a string/bytes object in a  loop should have quadratic behavior. Recent versions try to optimize this, but it isn't always successful, and is a well known anti-pattern that you should avoid. Use `.join` Note, in Python 2, `bytes` is merely an alias for `str`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Quite interesting. Neither `str` nor `bytes` concatenation in Python 2 appear to have quadratic time.

Comment: because in Python 2 `str is bytes`. Like I said, in Python 3, this optimization was kept for `str`, but apparently didn't bother with `bytes`. Again, it is a well known and expected behavior, what is more surprising *should be the optimized linear behavior*. Just use join. Don't use reduce (same problem). Note, `sum` even raises an error if you try to use it with strings `sum(['a','b','c'], '')`. Good question overall, BTW

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Concatenating strings with `+` or `+=` in a loop was never a good idea. It only seemed efficient because there was a [weird, controversial special case](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v2.7.15/Python/ceval.c#L1734) in the bytecode interpreter loop which would attempt to concatenate strings mutatively if it could prove no one else had a reference to the string it was messing with. There was no efficient resize policy in place; it just [called `realloc`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v2.7.15/Objects/stringobject.c#L3907) and hoped for the best, so it could still end up O(n^2) if `realloc` needed to copy.

In Python 3, that [weird special case](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.5/Python/ceval.c#L1679) now handles unicode strings instead of bytestrings. Bytestring concatenation goes back to building a new string object each time, so your loop goes back to O(n^2).

Comment: Quite interesting. Why would they drop that optimization, though? It seems like a popular-enough thing that people try (even if it is a bad idea).

Comment: @Reinderien well, they kept it for `str` (equivalentish to Python 2 `unicode`), which is the common newby use-case. If you are fiddling around with `bytes` you should know better anyway.